# non-lethal military force

Tags: technology, technological-development, military

A non lethal military force goes both ways, it's not just about not killing the enemy while also capturing them, this is the easy part.

But also about not getting killed yourself, this is the hard part.
The military force is not a defensive or pacifist one, it instead actively seeks to dominate the resources of other countries and will **always** strike first.

**reason**

See this as an ''Utopic  military and humanistic dictatorship''

The dictators see the humans as their children, idiotic foolish and infantile children that must be taken care of and loved even at their worst. But a parent must also impose their authority.
Kind of like the hebrew god in the bible, except this god figure of a dictator doesn't send pest and tempests of fire to punish it's own children for fighting but first makes them stop and then reasons with them, just like parent or teacher separating two kids fighting.

Therefore each single soldier is incredibly valuable and can't be lost in battle, would you ever sacrifice your own children to save another?

**question**

How to make infantry un-killable by human tools?

**clarifications**

The infantry is both used to stop other military forces from fighting each other and also to invade and conquer.

**Who is the dictator**

The dictator has died long ago but has been kept in a vegetative state for the last 98 years.

a very simple artificial intelligence or ''protocol'' is leeching the memories of the of the dictator, every time the artificial intelligence violates the code, it is killed and replaced with a new generation.

Therefore it is automatic that only the best ruler will ever be alive at any time, it is impossible to have an inferior ruler than the previous ones because like all artificial intelligences, the next generations learn from the mistakes of the older ones (unlike filthy humans who literally do the opposite and fight the young)

the protocol follows a simple code of rules and the death of the artificial intelligence depends on whether or not it will cause the death of humans or how much happiness will it bring to the world.

The dictator has the memories of a real human who actually experienced **Agape** love and the coldness of a machine.

**More specifics of the artificial intelligence**

As I said it is really simple and is more resembling of a talking economic and political spreadsheet with actual military power than an actual sci-fi movie airticial intelligece, the decisions are made based on calculations of the errors from the previous generations, predictions and the memories of the dead dictator.

The Artificial intelligence is not stuck into any hard disk but free to use every server connected to internet and with access to means of ''convincing'' politicians to obey. It can access anything on the internet and enmasse absurds amounts of informations in mere minutes, information which will be vital to their decisions and predictions.

privacy does not exist, if one has something to hide, the dictator knows it.

The dictator code can't be modified or accessed, and if someone tried or even just talked about it, the dictator would know it.

and even if one version of the dictator in some server managed to get corrupted, it works kind of like the blockchain, the remaining non corrupt versions will correct the corrupt one.

Comment: Could you maybe winnow this down to the actual question? It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. written in bold **Question**

Comment: @ARogueAnt. **''How to make infantry un-killable by human tools?''** there are only 3 question marks, 2 of which are obvious rhetorical  questions

Comment: Ah, got it now. comments deleted. I think the formatting and my eyes were incompatible for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 2):

## Kriegsspiel:

How better to treat humans as children than to turn war into a game?

Okay, this is an oversimplification, but fundamentally, European wars allowed prisoners to be granted a wide variety of mercies. Prisoners were ransomed, and both side respected the system because both sides understood that if you kill everyone in a war, after a generation there will be no one left to be citizens, let alone warriors.

The Japanese system developed around elaborate codes of honor and sacrifice (sounds good, right?). The result was that warriors who didn't sacrifice themselves for the greater good of the cause and Emperor were despised, mistreated, and generally considered less than human.

**Make War Like A Boardgame:** Take the European model to it's absolute extreme, and implement a system where both the government and their rivals are treated with great respect. If an enemy surrenders, he/she can expect good treatment, possibly immunity from questioning (after all, it's a police state; do you really need human intelligence?) and likely expect to be paroled back to their side as part of a prisoner exchange. There are clear and very fairly enforced rules of engagement everyone agrees on.

BUT WAIT! This doesn't sound terrible or authoritarian! Well, it's not. The government is quasi-benevolent. You hope your enemy will learn to respect the need for authority, and eventually grow up and buckle down. What better way than to give those guys every reason to surrender rather than fight to the death? And similarly, government troopers presented with a situation that terrorists/rebels/enemies could kill them immediately surrender - even voluntarily assisting with their incarceration to minimize the inconvenience. The government may even pay the rebels/rivals for the upkeep of soldiers in enemy hands.

**The rebels inflict maximum cost and inconvenience on the government by capturing soldiers**, so they are happy. KILLING soldiers results in a huge PR bonus for the government, and a perfect excuse to brutalize them, since they violated the very fair and even-handed rules of war. The government gets to save their soldiers, save the enemy, and have virtually bloodless wars.

You might need a genuinely impartial set of ["Kriegsspiel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriegsspiel) judges moderating the conflict to prevent either side from feeling exploited. War will become nearly bloodless as it transitions to a glorified board game where everyone expects to be treated with human dignity.

## ALTERNATIVE:

- If the difficulty is controlling your enemy and HIS lethal actions, give him nothing to kill. Your government is based around an advanced AI, so use robots equipped with capture devices, less-lethal weapons, etc. Endless industrially-produced drones, bots, AI vehicles, come churning out of your factories. The AI either uses programmed machines OR copies itself into the bots and continuously downloads backups of the copy in the weapon, so it isn't dying (even if the robot is destroyed). That way, you control your side, and the enemy can't kill soldiers that aren't in harm's way, because you almost never USE soldiers.

Answer (score 1):

Your benevolent despot needs to wield god-like power.  There must be such a large gap between the weakest of the dictator's forces and the greatest of the enemy's forces, that both sides of civilian squabble immediately surrender when the dictator's forces join the field.

For this to believable, your AI would need to be a little more science-fiction then its current machine-learning capabilities, but the idea that an AI augmented technocracy could have that level of advantage over its subject is not unusual in modern fiction.

It is probably not possible to make the dictator's infantry completely death-proof, but you could easily make the consequences of killing any of the dictator's representatives so dire that no sane enemy leader would ever allow it to happen.

Comment: I mostly agree with this answer, but I'd like to point out that these god-like powers have to rise to the level of being able to achieve victory without killing the rebels. Humans have a well-documented aversion to this stuff, and in extreme cases they are willing to commit mass suicide to escape such. The AI has to be able to prevent that (or resurrect them after) or it'd end up provoking some sort of worldwide Masada.

Answer (score 1):

### Wireless dominance.

The AI uses their superior mastery of the internet and technology to ensure any networked technology doesn't work. This means enemies are scattered and confused. They can try to use non wireless options, but then they face a fully networked military with vastly better coordination and precision weapons.

### Lots of artillery.

Fighting person to person is dangerous, and could lead to deaths. As such, they should use artillery.

They could use glue bombs, tear gas bombs, or stun bombs to disable people, using their manufacturing capacity and networked nature to outgun their enemy.

Every shell can have precision networked guidance from the AI to make them more precise, so every shell can count.

### Heavy vehicles for most interactions with enemies.

Human bodies are pretty fragile. As such, the army will make heavy use of vehicles to protect their soldiers from any attempt to kill people. They can bombard enemies from afar, spread propaganda, and avoid any direct confrontations.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make infantry un-killable by human tools?

There's only one way to do this, and that's to never actually commit infantry to the field. Never expose them to any risk.

In the real world that's not possible, but we're not all that far off. Drones are your solution. Not the high flying missile armed drones of the current age, but smaller and ground based drones with the precision required to neutralise an individual target in a confined space.

Like any good dictatorship, the infantry are really just for the grand parades. Their job is to march up and down in perfect time for all the great and good who have dutifully come to see the show.

Answer (score 0):

/The military force is not a defensive or pacifist one, it instead actively seeks to dominate the resources of other countries and will always strike first./

**Your soldiers are bankers.**

They do not enter the foreign country personally, but via electronics and local proxies. They ensure that money is electronic by making the use of electronic money cheaper and easier than gold coins or paper.  They manipulate the flow of money to ensure the development of the country in question meets their goals.  Criminal enterprises will be made obvious in this way, and tolerated as long as their existence furthers the ends of your banker / soldiers.  Persons enriching themselves to the detriment of the state (and bankers controlling it) will be gently taxed such that the correct proportion of their energies advance the cause of the nation.  Even the fiercest soldier needs to eat.  If there is not money available to buy him food he will find something else to do.

These bankers are not invaders.  They were invited in to do this job.  The job is to protect the people from evil and from themselves.  Money is perfectly suited as the tool for this job.